# different AIC from drop1 function and AIC function

Tags: r, glm, vgam

I'm using stepwise removal of variable for a glm using drop1.

From model 1,  I am dropping the variable with the lowest AIC as required producing model 2.

However, when I then compare the AIC of the two the AIC of model 1 is lower and the AIC reported from `drop1` for model2 and the AIC reported from `AIC()` are different.

I'm confused why these AICs for the same model from `drop1()` and `AIC()` and how to go about model selection given this?

Thanks

```
m1 <- glm(abundance ~ treatment + land_use + patch_size, data=df)

drop1(m1, test="F")

m2 <- glm(abundance ~ treatment + land_use, data=df)

AIC(m1) 

AIC(m2) ##this AIC varies from that reported in drop1() and is higher than AIC(m1)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The `drop1` function uses `extractAIC` to get the AIC, while the `AIC` function uses a different additive constant.  See the Details section of `?extractAIC`, specifically this paragraph:

> For linear models with unknown scale (i.e., for ‘lm’ and ‘aov’), -2
> log L is computed from the *deviance* and uses a different additive
> constant to ‘logLik’ and hence ‘AIC’.  If RSS denotes the (weighted)
> residual sum of squares then ‘extractAIC’ uses for -2 log L the
> formulae RSS/s - n (corresponding to Mallows' Cp) in the case of known
> scale s and n log (RSS/n) for unknown scale.  ‘AIC’ only handles
> unknown scale and uses the formula n * log(RSS/n) + n + n * log 2pi -
> sum(log w) where w are the weights.  Further ‘AIC’ counts the scale
> estimation as a parameter in the ‘edf’ and ‘extractAIC’ does not.

However, as it goes on to say:

> Note that the methods for this function may differ in their
> assumptions from those of methods for ‘AIC’ (usually *via* a method
> for ‘logLik’).  We have already mentioned the case of ‘"lm"’ models
> with estimated scale, and there are similar issues in the ‘"glm"’ and
> ‘"negbin"’ methods where the dispersion parameter may or may not be
> taken as ‘free’.  This is immaterial as ‘extractAIC’ is only used to
> compare models of the same class (where only differences in AIC values
> are considered).

So in other words, you could implement your own `drop1` function using `AIC`, and you'd get the same *differences* between the AICs of the various submodels and the AIC of the full model that you do with the built-in `drop1`.